# gurobi, do not have a specific range of values,

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization, gurobi

`x` is a decision variable.
How to build a constraint that meets the following conditions?

```
(x >= 100) or (x <= 50)
```

How can the two expressions below be combined under `or` condition?

```
mdl.addConstr(x>=100) 
mdl.addConstr(x<=50)
```

Comment: You can define variables`x1 >= 100`, `x2 <= 50`, and `b` binary. Then, replace `x` with `x1 * b + x2 * (1-b)`.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, such formulations have some other dependencies to define when either of the constraints is supposed to hold. Here, [indicator constraints](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/py_model_agc_indicator.html) can be used:

```
mdl.addConstr((y == 0) >> (x <= 50))
mdl.addConstr((y == 1) >> (x >= 100))
```

The binary variable `y` is used to switch on either one of the two constraints.